# Our cube is slow and SSAS is running some odd MDX member queries

Tags: ssas, mdx

We have a slow performing cube that seems to slow down drastically when looking at stuff at the product level. It took around 6 minutes to refresh when our legacy cube showing the same data is almost instant. I fired up the Profiler and found that it was running queries like the above many times for all the products filtered:

```
>     WITH MEMBER [Product].[Style].[XL_PT0] AS 'strtomember("[Product].[Style].&[BA30259]").UniqueName' MEMBER
> [Product].[Style].[XL_PT1] AS
> 'strtomember("[Product].[Style].&[BA30258]").UniqueName' MEMBER
> [Product].[Style].[XL_PT2] AS
> 'strtomember("[Product].[Style].&[BA30257]").UniqueName' ..........
> SELECT {[Product].[Style].[XL_PT0],[Product].[Style].[XL_PT1]...... ON
> 0 FROM [Retail] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Just a lot of the above queries which is doing a strtomember on ALOT of values.
Why could this be?

Comment: find out who is doing those queries with ssas DMVs

Comment: @mxix I know who it is... It's me running that through excel.